# Fetch data from .USX file using php

Tags: php, xml

I have one .usx file and i want to fetch data from it accordingly. But now finding any way to do it. Please help me out.
[usx file link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openbibleinfo/American-Standard-Version-Bible/master/usx/01-GEN.usx)

I had tried the below code

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("uploads/American-Standard-Version-Bible-master/usx/01-GEN.usx") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($xml->children() as $book)
{
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($book);

     echo "Book Name:".$book->attributes()->code."<br/>";
    if($book->attributes()->number != "" )
    {
         echo "chapter : ".$book->attributes()->number."<br />";
    }
    foreach ($book->verse as $value) {
      // echo "<pre>";
      // print_r($value);
       echo "Verses Number : ".$value->attributes()->number."<br />";
    }

    echo "book : ".$book."<br />";
    echo "<hr/>";


}

}
```

OUTPUT : 
[image: this is the output]

I want output one by one of all verse rather then all at once

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry Magnus i had edited my question

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be that SimpleXML just doesn't give you enough control over XML that has more than a simple structure.  So trying to get the text inbetween the `<verse>` tags is difficult.  If instead you use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), this has much more detail and control over your document.

The code below just reads through the document and mostly checks the node names to work out what it should be displaying - so for the `<chapter>` element, it will output the number attribute.  The only difference is that when looking through the main `<para>` elements which contain the `<verse>` and text mixed together, it looks for a node type of `XML_TEXT_NODE`, which as you might expect is the verse text, so it just outputs the contents at that point.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->load("01-GEN.usx");

foreach ( $dom->documentElement->childNodes as $element )    {
    if ( $element->nodeName == "book" )    {
        echo "Book Name:".$element->getAttribute("code")."<br/>";
    }
    else if ( $element->nodeName == "chapter" )    {
        echo "chapter:".$element->getAttribute("number")."<br/>";
    }
    else if ( $element->nodeName == "para" )    {
        foreach ( $element->childNodes as $verse )    {
            if ( $verse->nodeName == "verse" )    {
                echo "verse:".$verse->getAttribute("number")."<br/>";
            }
            else if ( $verse->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE )   {
                echo $verse->nodeValue."<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```